# How do you divide in the select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get the quotient of two columns inside the select statement. Here's what I have tried.

```
Select ( select sum(x.amount) amount
         from this_table x
         where x.acct_no = '52'
       ) / 
       ( select sum(x.amount) amount
         from this_table x
         where x.acct_no = '53'
       ) as amount
from this_table y
join this_table x on x.acct_no = y.acct_no
where x.acct_no = '52' or x.acct_no = '53'
```

When I do this, my amount column just comes out as 1, and I'm positive that isn't what the result should be. Any advice or help? Solution?

Comment: The *table definition* would be in order. Then we'd see the data type of `amount` and get an idea why your numbers are quoted like strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do as you want:

```
select  sum(case when acct_no = '52' then amount else 0 end)
      / sum(case when acct_no = '53' then amount else 0 end) as amount
from    this_table
where   acct_no in ('52','53')
```

To make the amount column show zero if the divisor is zero (rather than return an error), you can use:

```
select  case when sum(case when acct_no = '53' then amount else 0 end) = 0 then 0
        else
        sum(case when acct_no = '52' then amount else 0 end)
      / sum(case when acct_no = '53' then amount else 0 end) end as amount
from    this_table
where   acct_no in ('52','53')
```

May be useful if you plan on doing this often and/or using the results in an application where you don't want an error thrown back at you.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll find out the rest from here. I guess the data didn't want it from number 53, because I got a division by zero. Thanks though, that really helped.

Comment: No problem, you can wrap the case statement that calculates the divisor into another case statement, assigning a zero or some other value when the divisor is zero (to prevent the error, if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Cast to numeric

```
select 3 / 2;
 ?column? 
----------
        1

select 3::numeric / 2;
      ?column?      
--------------------
 1.5000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do you:

```
select ratio = sum(cast( case t.acct_no when '52' then t.amount else 0.00 end as numeric(15,2) )
             / sum(cast( case t.acct-no when '53' then t.amount else 0.00 end as numeric(15,2) )
from this_table t
where t.acct_no in ( '52' , '53' )
```

You might not need the `cast` if `amount` is a suitable data type.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I just had a play in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1606 ,  and if you're only after a single row single column result, PostgreSQL seems to allow :

```
WITH Amounts52 as (select   23 as sum52),
     Amounts53 as (select 4356 as sum53)
SELECT Amounts52.sum52::float
     / Amounts53.sum53  AS Result
FROM Amounts52, Amounts53
```

So you can put your `Sum()` queries in the two Common Table Expressions and get a the single result - if this approach appeals to you (it has its uses)

Of course it is a lot simpler to use this ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1924/0 ) :

```
SELECT (select   23 as sum52)
      /(select 4356 as sum53)::float AS Answer
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic statement would be:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT sum(amount)::numeric   FROM this_table WHERE acct_no = '52')  /
  (SELECT NULLIF(sum(amount), 0) FROM this_table WHERE acct_no = '53') AS div
```

- [`NULLIF`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) prevents `division by 0`. You get `NULL` in this case, which is the appropriate result.
- If `amount` is some kind of integer, cast to a [numeric type with more precision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) to preserve fractional digits. (You may want [`round()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE).) One cast is enough, the result is in the data-type with the greater precision. Relevance dependings on your actual types.
- A single query with `CASE` statements [like @Brian provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23642752/939860) may be faster. With an index it hardly matters.
- Am index on `(acct_no)` makes this fast, a multicolumn index on `(acct_no, amount)` even faster, if [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) (Postgres 9.2+) are possible.